# how to reset security question

Tags: security, apple-id, password

I forgot the answer to my security question and no email to rescue mail received.

How can I change my rescue email? Or is there a way to change the answer to something like "used code for mobile No."?

Comment: My experience has been that if you do not have a rescue email, and you do not know at least two of the security responses, you're out of luck. I recently went through this with an Apple rep regarding another user's Apple ID. I could tell them the date the account was set up, the original Apple ID, the original password, the original owner, every app that was purchased, and when, and a lot more... but the fact that I didn't know the security responses, and the rescue email no longer existed meant I could not access the account. I ended up setting up a new one.

Comment: Why can't you receive the email? Can't you reactivate your email account, you used?

Comment: Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82107/how-can-you-reset-security-questions-on-an-apple-id-when-you-have-the-password

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot remember the answer, the only Way for you would be to get this rescue email going. You cannot change any details of your account without that email.

Try to rescue your email-account, you used to get the email.